# Given a group homomorphism $R \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} M \rightarrow M$, I need to show that this makes $M$ into a left $R$-module.

Tags: tensor-products

> Given a group homomorphism $R \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} M \rightarrow M$, I need to show that this makes $M$ into a left $R$-module.

We can see that

$\bullet$ $r(m+m') = r \otimes (m+m') = r \otimes m + r \otimes m' = rm + rm'$

$\bullet$ $(r+r')m = (r+r') \otimes m = r \otimes m + r' \otimes m = rm + r'm$

$\bullet$ $(rr')m = rr' \otimes m = r \otimes r'm = r(r'm)$

$\bullet$ $1m = 1 \otimes m = m$

I have a question about the third one, where I used $rr' \otimes m = r \otimes r'm$. Is this valid? Because we are tensoring over $\Bbb{Z}$ and not over $R$, right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Three looks fishy since, as you say, you're tensoring over the integers...besides this, $\;R\;$ is a commutative (and, apparently, unitary) ring, right?

Comment: You're probably confusing yourself somewhat by writing $rm = r \otimes m$ when you really mean $rm = \mu(r \otimes m)$. (where I've used $\mu$ for your unnamed group homomorphism)

Comment: Are you sure you have the question right? e.g. you *can* put a left $R$-module structure on $R \otimes_\mathbb{Z} M$.

Comment: @DonAntonio There are no assumptions for $R$.

Comment: Then i think this is due to be false, @Erciyes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is true, take for instance $R=\Bbb Z[X]$, then you can define a morphism $\Bbb Z[X]\otimes_{\Bbb Z}M$ by sending $P\otimes m$ to $$\left(\sum_{i\geq 0} a_ic_i\right)m$$ where $(c_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is some sequence of integers, and $P=\sum_{i\geq 0}a_iX^i$. This, in general, does not define a $\Bbb Z[X]$-module structure on $M$.

---

Actually, there is no reason to assume a general map of groups should map $1\otimes m$ to $m$ either. For instance, this fails when $R=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ and $M=\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$, since $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z=0$.

Answer (score 1):

One could try with $rm=\varphi(r\otimes m)$, where $\varphi\colon R\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}M\to M$ is the given group homomorphism.

Then $(r+s)m=\varphi((r+s)\otimes m))$, $r(m+n)=\varphi(r\otimes(m+n))$ don't pose problems.

The problem is with
$$
r(sm)=\varphi(r\otimes(sm))=\varphi(r\otimes(\varphi(s\otimes m)))
$$
while
$$
(rs)m=\varphi((rs)\otimes m))
$$

So, without some more hypotheses on $\varphi$, I'd say this is not true.

Comment: So do you think there is a problem with the question?

Comment: @Erciyes Yes, Olivier's answer shows an example.